# Debug unexpected fault address in go tests

Tags: go

I have a Go binary for which I by now have a few tests, which are all supposed to run parallel.
As such, I have a lot of `_test` packages and all `Test`* include a call to `t.Parallel()`.

The Go binary uses 2 third-party modules, where I already found (and fixed) concurrency problems. No obvious concurrency problem exists to me. Also running using `-race` yields no complaint.

Now executing all test with `go clean -testcache && go test ./...` gets me every 4th run or so:

```
Unexpected fault address 0x2d84420
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x2d84420 pc=0x4730e5]

goroutine 15 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x129fe7b, 0x5)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72 fp=0xc000074810 sp=0xc0000747e0 pc=0x439612
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:727 +0x405 fp=0xc000074840 sp=0xc000074810 pc=0x44fda5
runtime.memmove(0xc000680000, 0x1236820, 0x1b4dc80)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/runtime/memmove_amd64.s:392 +0x485 fp=0xc000074848 sp=0xc000074840 pc=0x4730e5
fmt.(*buffer).writeString(...)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/print.go:82
fmt.(*fmt).padString(0xc00009f2f0, 0x1236820, 0x1b4dc80)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/format.go:110 +0x8e fp=0xc0000748d0 sp=0xc000074848 pc=0x4f288e
fmt.(*fmt).fmtS(0xc00009f2f0, 0x1236820, 0x1b4dc80)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/format.go:359 +0x65 fp=0xc000074908 sp=0xc0000748d0 pc=0x4f37c5
fmt.(*pp).fmtString(0xc00009f2b0, 0x1236820, 0x1b4dc80, 0x73)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/print.go:450 +0x1ba fp=0xc000074958 sp=0xc000074908 pc=0x4f6dfa
fmt.(*pp).printArg(0xc00009f2b0, 0x10a2320, 0xc0004c8cf0, 0x73)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/print.go:698 +0x7e7 fp=0xc0000749f0 sp=0xc000074958 pc=0x4f9147
fmt.(*pp).doPrintf(0xc00009f2b0, 0x129f741, 0x5, 0xc000074bb8, 0x2, 0x2)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/print.go:1030 +0x168 fp=0xc000074ad8 sp=0xc0000749f0 pc=0x4fc208
fmt.Sprintf(0x129f741, 0x5, 0xc000074bb8, 0x2, 0x2, 0xe300000001b7f5f0, 0x1b4f180)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/fmt/print.go:219 +0x66 fp=0xc000074b30 sp=0xc000074ad8 pc=0x4f54a6
github.com/grantstreetgroup/go-exasol-client.(*Conn).wsConnect(0xc0004a1680)
        /user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grantstreetgroup/go-exasol-client@v0.0.0-20201009202215-417bc9d41dc2/websocket.go:33 +0xea fp=0xc000074c78 sp=0xc000074b30 pc=0x7a7daa
github.com/grantstreetgroup/go-exasol-client.Connect(0x1236820, 0x1b4dc80, 0xc00063fe10, 0x129ebb5, 0x3, 0x12a1065, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grantstreetgroup/go-exasol-client@v0.0.0-20201009202215-417bc9d41dc2/client.go:84 +0x113 fp=0xc000074cb0 sp=0xc000074c78 pc=0x7a2253
github.com/abergmeier/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/exaprovider.newConnect(0x1236820, 0x1b4dc80, 0xc00063fe10, 0x129ebb5, 0x3, 0x12a1065, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /user/Projects/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/exaprovider/client.go:28 +0x45 fp=0xc000074d30 sp=0xc000074cb0 pc=0x7aa005
github.com/abergmeier/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/exaprovider.(*Client).Lock(...)
        /user/Projects/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/exaprovider/client.go:35
github.com/abergmeier/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test_test.TestAccExasolRole_import(0xc0003f9800)
        /user/Projects/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test/role_acc_test.go:61 +0x178 fp=0xc000074f80 sp=0xc000074d30 pc=0xfeb0f8
testing.tRunner(0xc0003f9800, 0x12ee108)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0xef fp=0xc000074fd0 sp=0xc000074f80 pc=0x529f8f
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374 +0x1 fp=0xc000074fd8 sp=0xc000074fd0 pc=0x471e61
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1178 +0x386

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc0003f9800, 0x12b54a8, 0x18, 0x12ee108, 0x49b701)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1179 +0x3ad
testing.runTests.func1(0xc0003f9380)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1449 +0x78
testing.tRunner(0xc0003f9380, 0xc00063fc00)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0xef
testing.runTests(0xc0004c4940, 0x1b37060, 0x2, 0x2, 0xbfdb48dc53e2df3f, 0x8bb3466227, 0x1b4df40, 0x40f948)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1447 +0x2e8
testing.(*M).Run(0xc00019ad00, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1357 +0x245
github.com/abergmeier/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test_test.testRun(0xc00019ad00, 0x0)
        /user/Projects/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test/main_test.go:28 +0x136
github.com/abergmeier/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test_test.TestMain(0xc00019ad00)
        /user/Projects/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test/main_test.go:20 +0x85
main.main()
        _testmain.go:47 +0x165

goroutine 6 [select]:
go.opencensus.io/stats/view.(*worker).start(0xc00019a700)
        /user/go/pkg/mod/go.opencensus.io@v0.22.4/stats/view/worker.go:276 +0x105
created by go.opencensus.io/stats/view.init.0
        /user/go/pkg/mod/go.opencensus.io@v0.22.4/stats/view/worker.go:34 +0x68

goroutine 14 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Parallel(0xc0003f9500)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1003 +0x20b
github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2/helper/resource.ParallelTest(0x147e120, 0xc0003f9500, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0004d4f30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0003f9680, ...)
        /user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/v2@v2.0.4/helper/resource/testing.go:482 +0x63
github.com/abergmeier/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test_test.TestAccExasolRole_rename(0xc0003f9500)
        /user/Projects/terraform-provider-exasol/internal/resources/role_test/role_acc_test.go:26 +0x878
testing.tRunner(0xc0003f9500, 0x12ee110)
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1127 +0xef
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/lib/go-1.15/src/testing/testing.go:1178 +0x386
```

The stacktrace there is always similar.

I looked into `/user/go/pkg/mod/github.com/grantstreetgroup/go-exasol-client@v0.0.0-20201009202215-417bc9d41dc2/websocket.go:33` and I am very doubtful that it is actually the culprit (`Sprintf` and active objects seem innocent enough).

I tried running with `valgrind --error-limit=no --track-origins=yes` but seemed to be no smoking gun. Especially since nowhere in the output would be a mention of `0x2d84420`.

I tried running via `dlv` but there seems to be now way of attaching to recursive started tests.

By now I am somewhat out of ideas and would appreciate any concrete steps how to hone in on the source of the faulty address.

Bonus points if someone could clear up whether `0x2d84420` is supposed to be a logical (Go) or physical (Linux) address.

Output of `go version` is:

```
go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

So I rewrote the third-party module's function to not use `Sprintf` and now it claims to fail on:

```
Host:   host + ":" + port,
```

with both `host` and `port` being of type `string`.
So currently I would assume that stacktrace is bogus. Maybe due to missing debug symbols?

**EDIT 2:**

By now I am somehow thinking that I might be triggering some kind of undefined behavior. It seems like `Port` sometimes gets corrupted before. I tried testing `Port` for (corrupted) value `65040` and it seems to get corrupted soon after `TestMain`. I deleted some non-essential code and now the corrupted value is `65056`.

Comment: The arguments to Sprintf may be modified by another goroutine concurrently, causing a race condition. It might be seeing a partially constructed map, etc.

Comment: If you look at the code, the erroring function is actually called only once on a new instance of `Conn`. There is no other routine, that has access to any of these memory regions AFAIS.

Comment: It even happens with `GCO_ENABLED=0`

Comment: Using `GOTRACEBACK=crash` I now have a core dump. Will try to figure out how to analyse it.

Answer (score 1):

So I changed the `TestMain` from

```
var (
    exaClient *exaprovider.Client
    exaConf   exasol.ConnConf
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    flag.Parse()
    os.Exit(testRun(m))
}

func testRun(m *testing.M) int {
    exaConf = internal.MustCreateTestConf()
    exaClient = exaprovider.NewClient(exaConf)

    return m.Run()
}
```

to

```
var (
    exaClient *exaprovider.Client
    exaConf   exasol.ConnConf
)

func init() {
    exaConf = internal.MustCreateTestConf()
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    flag.Parse()
    os.Exit(testRun(m))
}

func testRun(m *testing.M) int {
    exaClient = exaprovider.NewClient(exaConf)

    return m.Run()
}
```

and all corruptions seem gone. It is official - I do not understand golang anymore.